# How to capture the user command, when a python script is called?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have a python script `myscript.py`, which takes multiple named arguments. The user calls the script as `python myscript.py --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2`. How to capture this whole command (i.e. `python myscript.py --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2` ) and save it to a text file "command.selfie" using the same script that the user is calling?

Comment: You are looking for `sys.argv`: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sys.argv is a list with all the arguments.
This will help:

```
import sys
command = " ".join(sys.argv)
# do whatever you want to do with command: str
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import argparse
import sys

def main(argv):
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("--arg1", default=False, help="Explain arg1")
   parser.add_argument("--arg2", type=str, default="hello", help="Explain arg2")
   # add all arguments you need

   args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])       
   params = {"arg1": args.arg1,
             "arg2": args.arg2, }

   print(params["arg1"])
   print(params["arg2"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```